# Clear input type file value after cloning it

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload, input

I am working on a form in which if a user selects a file, it will duplicate that input and append it after the first one. This part works well except since I am using the clone property, it is also copying the value when it adds another input of type file.

I would like to set this cloned input back to the default value of "browse". How can I accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This appears to only be happening in Firefox. Chrome and IE do not have this issue.

jQuery:

```
$('#attach').on("change", "input[type=file]:last", function() {
    var item = $(this).clone(true);
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    if (fileName){
        $(this).parent().append("<br />").append(item); 
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr id="FileAttachmentRow">
    <td id="attach"><label for="CAT_Custom_2">File Upload</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="FileAttachment[]" id="FileAttachment" class="cat_textbox FileAttachment" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `item.val('')` doesnt work?

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon It works once, then it won't clone a second time.

Comment: @j08691 This appears to be a Firefox specific problem after checking into it.